# django: factory boy in south datamigrations?

Tags: django, django-south, fixtures, django-fixtures, factory-boy

In the past we used south datamigrations to update the data in tables.

For fixtures we want to use factory boy in the future.

Inside a south datamigration I have only the `orm`, and must not import the real models.

Is it possible to use factory boy inside south datamigrations?

Background: I want to reuse code in both places:

- south datamigrations
- unittests

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: @danielfranca what should be more specific? I thought the question does not need an example, but may be I am wrong. The short answer: there seems to be no way to use factory boy inside south datamigrations.